# Any good sefarim to learn basics of Kodshim?

Tags: product-recommendation, korban, kodshim

does anyone know of any Seforim that are good introductions/ basics of Kodshim? (They can be in Hebrew/ English)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: This may help as well http://baishamikdash.com/bh_html/index.html

Comment: Many seforim on kodshim have some type of introduction. Tiferes yisroel is quite good with his why where what when with how introduction. Have I left one out?

Comment: For mishna or gemarah as well?

Answer (score 2):

When you get to Chullin the sefer [Chullin Illuminated](https://www.feldheim.com/chullin-illuminated.html) is a really practical and helpful pictorial guide.

When moving on to Gemara you might want to consider the first Chief Rabbi of Warsaw, [Rav Shlomo Zalman Lifshitz](https://dailyzohar.com/tzadikim/328-Rabbi-Shlomo-Zalman-Lifshitz)'s Sefer Olas Shlomo (he is perhaps more famously known as the author of Chemdas Shlomo) which is a two-volume clear p'shat-based sefer that covers the full seder kodshim. It is available on Hebrewbooks [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/20961) and [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/20997).

Comment: The main 'picture book' on chullin is sichas chullin

Comment: Sharei Heichal is a great sefer for learning Zevachim,has alot of great pictures and commentary

Answer (score 1):

Go through the Rambam on Avodah.

Start with [Hilchos Maashe HaKorbonos](https://rambam.alhatorah.org/Full/Ma%27aseh_HaKorbanot/1.1#e0n6).

Comment: and which nosei keilim do you reccomend?

Comment: If you are just looking for a basic idea start with out the nosie keilim

Comment: I would hardly call the Yad Hachazaka an introductory/basics seffer. The sheer amount of super commentaries should prove that.

Comment: Rambam's intro to Mishna Zevachim is a much better choice.

Comment: The best nosei keilim on the rambam I would choose aruch hashulchan hoosid.